# Do you put a comma around "as well"

Tags: commas, adverbs, conjunctions, adverb-position

Would I write, "He, as well, no longer held the need to impress her" or "He as well no longer held the need to impress her"?

Which is grammatically correct?

Comment: _held the need_ is rather unidiomatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the dependent clause in the middle of the sentence like that (between subject and action), then you would "need" to couch it in commas to set it off from the rest of the phrase, and because you would pause there, anyway (read it out loud).

If you moved that modifier -- it's almost like an adverb, come to think of it [["as" definitely is]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as) -- to the end of the sentence, you would only need one to set it off.

> He no longer held the need to impress her, as well.

But then you have to be careful with the semantics in context, and make sure that the sentence before doesn't make it ambiguous -- indeed, reducing ambiguity would be the strongest argument to jam it as close to the subject as possible, commas be damned.

Comment: 1) _as well_ is not a dependent clause. 2) You're using _couch_ incorrectly. 3)  At the end of the sentence there is no way _as well_ can still modify _he_. 4) _As well_ is like also, so no need for commas.

Comment: 1) Yes, it is. There is an omitted syntactic referent to which **as** refers, @KarlG . "He, as well as her parents, no longer held the need to impress her." 2) Yes, I am. https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/couch_2 3) Yes, it can. "Her parents no longer felt the need to impress her. He no longer held the need to impress her, as well." 4) ? The question makes no mention of "also," but those differences are outlined here in more detail than your comment.

Comment: _To couch_ something in a particular way means to express it, as that definition suggests.  _Couched in obscure language, couched in terms of…_ To use it to refer to punctuation is highly unidiomatic.